# Returning incorrect value from class

Tags: c++, qt, lifetime, temporary

I have the following class:

```
class RequestBuilder : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
   public:
    static RequestBuilder& getInstance()
    {
        static RequestBuilder instance;
        return instance;
    }
    RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder const&) = delete;
    void operator=(RequestBuilder const&) = delete;

    void setUrl(const QString& url){ url_ = url; };
    QString url() const { return url_; };
private:
    RequestBuilder(){};
    QString url_ = "some_string";
};
```

1.) When I call it like this I am getting some not readable bytes (messed output):

```
const char* val = RequestBuilder::getInstance().url().toStdString().c_str();
printVal(val);
```

2.) When I call it like this, the result is correct:

```
auto string = RequestBuilder::getInstance().url().toStdString();
const char* val = string.c_str();
printVal(val);
```

What am I doing wrong in first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `RequestBuilder::getInstance().url().toStdString()` returns is a [temporary object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime), which would be destroyed immediately after the full expression, after that the pointer `val` got from the temporary becomes dangled, any dereference on it leads to UB.

As you've showed when use a named variable, whose lifetime ends when it get out of the scope, in which `val` would remain valid.